# .htaccess redirection from subdomain to virtual folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

I would like to redirect all subdomains into an virtual folder (it's always the same document root folder destination) but keep the subdomain name in the URL (to retrieve it by code).

http://subdomain.example.com -> http://www.example.com/subdomain

1. The first id was a full redirection to the subfolder:

The redirection rules are working in the .htaccess. 
But to avoid creating alias for those folders is there a way to point thoses subDomains to the root (there are many subdomains)?

I have tried a dynamic rewrite rule based on this domain but without success.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$   
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/%1/$1 [R=302]
    RewriteRule ^thisSub/(.*)$ /$1 [L]  <-- can this be dynamic ?
```

2. I also tried another solution:

http://subdomain.example.com -> http://www.example.com/?mySub=subdomain to rewrite it later (hide and convert) to http://www.example.com/subdomain but without success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?mySub=%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mySub=(.*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/?$ ?mySub=$1 [NC,L]
```

What did i miss ?

Is there a better solution (redirect but keep somewhere the subdomain info to use it)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just leave the "subdoman" and do an internal rewrite instead of a redirection. That way the subdomain stays visible, you don't need to append the subdomain's host name inside the path (which will always cause issues) and you still can use the subdomains host name inside a script.

Comment: The client wants to migrate to https but without paying for a multi domain certificate (it has more than 120 sub domains). I'm then looking to a generic solution (there are too many sub domains to create for alias or symbolic links for each).

Comment: Sounds strange, a business that is not willing to pay for a SSL certificate?

Comment: I would say that a GET argument makes more sense, the value can then be stored inside the user session to be available for subsequent requests. That keeps the path itself clean.

Comment: If I understand this right, then with the last rule ("<-- can this be dynamic ?") you  try to remove the "subdomain name" again from the path of the redirected URL. Probably to regain a clean path, which does make sense. But then why put it in there in the first place? That would mean that you have to keep it for each and every request, which is extremely ugly. I definitely would recommend to keep such data inside the user session instead.

Comment: The changes are  to avoid the cost of a multi subdomain SSL certificate. I would like to keep the illusion of the personification and continue to display the subdomain in the url but they are all related to the root path. With the second solution (RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1?mySub=%1) is it possible to rewrite the query string **?mySub=** into **/subdomain** in the url (my rule don't work). Could this make more sense and be less complicated to maintain ?

Comment: 1. Multidomain certificates are free of charge these days. 2. You cannot "keep the illusion" to display a domain in the client where no SSL certificates, that simply won't work, for obvious reasons and 3. I fail to see why it should make more sense or be less complicated to place that hostname inside the path of a redirection. In contrary, in my eyes this is more complicated and I fail to see how that should work easily with an application logic.